# Adding two linked lists together in java

Tags: java

Hello there, 
             My lab assignment is to take two strings, convert them into linkedLists and add the linked lists up. I have managed to get them to a level where they could be added together but you can't carryover. I have been working on that part and can't seem to figure it out.

The code is typed below. Thank you!

I reverse the strings when they get inputed in. the output string also needs to be reversed.

```
Code package linkedlist;

import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 *
 * @author Spock-II
 */
public class LinkedList {

    public static LinkedInt Trueadd(LinkedInt A, LinkedInt B) {
        LinkedInt a = A;
        LinkedInt b = B;

        int next;
        LinkedInt sum = new LinkedInt();

        System.out.println("Switches!");
        if (a.size() > b.size()) {
            System.out.println("size: " + (a.size() - b.size()));
            int limit = a.size() - b.size();
            for (int i = 0; i < limit; i++) {
                b.addToLinkList("0", i);
                System.out.println("inloop b");
                System.out.println("i : " + i);
            }
            System.out.println("loop complete");
        } else if (a.size() < b.size()) {
            System.out.println("size: " + (b.size() - a.size()));
            int limit = b.size() - a.size();
            for (int i = 0; i < limit; i++) {
                a.addToLinkList("0", i);
                System.out.println("inloop b");
                System.out.println("i : " + i);

            }
            System.out.println("loop complete");
        }

        System.out.println("Switch overcame");


        int carryover = 0;
        while (a.head != null & b.head != null) {
            String[] carryCheck = (Integer.valueOf(a.head.getItem()) + Integer.valueOf(b.head.getItem()) + "").split("");
            if (carryCheck.length == 2) {


                sum.addToLinkList((Integer.valueOf(carryCheck[1])+carryover)+"", 0);
                carryover = Integer.valueOf(carryCheck[0]);
            } else {
                int i = Integer.valueOf(a.head.getItem()) + Integer.valueOf(b.head.getItem());
                sum.addToLinkList(i + "", 0);
            }

            System.out.println("a: " + a.head.getItem());
            System.out.println("b: " + b.head.getItem());
            a.head = a.head.getLink();
            b.head = b.head.getLink();
        }
        System.out.println("Completed");
        return sum;

    }

    public static LinkedInt subtract(LinkedInt a, LinkedInt b) {
        a.combine();
        b.combine();
        LinkedInt difference = new LinkedInt(a.x - b.x);
        difference.combine();
        return difference;

    }

    public static LinkedInt multiply(LinkedInt a, LinkedInt b) {
        a.combine();
        b.combine();
        LinkedInt product = new LinkedInt(a.x + b.x);
        product.combine();
        return product;

    }

    public static LinkedInt divide(LinkedInt a, LinkedInt b) {
        a.combine();
        b.combine();
        LinkedInt sum = new LinkedInt(a.x + b.x);
        sum.combine();
        return sum;

    }

    public static LinkedInt modulus(LinkedInt a, LinkedInt b) {
        a.combine();
        b.combine();
        LinkedInt rem = new LinkedInt(a.x + b.x);
        rem.combine();
        return rem;

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        Scanner i1 = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Please enter the first no. : ");
        int a = i1.nextInt();
        Scanner i2 = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Please enter the second no. : ");
        int b = i2.nextInt();
        System.out.println();

        LinkedInt a1 = new LinkedInt(a);
        LinkedInt a2 = new LinkedInt(b);
        a1 = a1.populate();
        a2 = a2.populate();
        a1.combine();
        a2.combine();

        LinkedInt sum = Trueadd(a1, a2);
        sum.combine2();

    //        LinkedInt sum = a1;
    }

}
`
```

Comment: This is not a site to get others to do your homework for you.  If you have tried, researched, and still find yourself stuck - then tell us what you tried, what you expect, and exactly where you think the problem in your code might be.

Comment: what is `LinkedInt`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know the exact structure of your `LinkedInt` class, but if it's a linkedList starting at the least significant digit, you should be able to do it change your loop to this:

```
    int carryover = 0;
    while (a.head != null & b.head != null) {
        int sumDigits = Integer.parseInt(a.head.getItem()) + Integer.parseInt(b.head.getItem())+carryover;
        // add least significant digit of sumDigits
        sum.addToLinkList(Integer.toString(sumDigits % 10), 0);
        // remove least significant digit from sumDigit to get the new carryover
        carryover = sumDigits / 10;
        a.head = a.head.getLink();
        b.head = b.head.getLink();
    }
    if (carryover != 0) {
        // if the last carryover isn't 0 add it as most significant digit of the result
        sum.addToLinkList(Integer.toString(carryover), 0);
    }
```

but in case you still want to convert between `String` and `int` as often as your code does, you need to add the carryover *before* converting to `String[]`, not after converting:

```
    while (a.head != null & b.head != null) {
        // add carryover here
        String[] carryCheck = (Integer.valueOf(a.head.getItem()) + Integer.valueOf(b.head.getItem()+carryover) + "").split("");
        if (carryCheck.length == 2) {

            // don't add carryover here
            sum.addToLinkList((Integer.valueOf(carryCheck[1]))+"", 0);
            carryover = Integer.valueOf(carryCheck[0]);
        } else {
            //...
    }
    // TODO: add carryover as most significant digit, if != 0
```